# Crashylitcs integration with android lib

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

I'm debugging stuff on a lib and was trying to integrate crashlytics on it. At first, I've followed [this](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/456258-library-subproject-in-gradle), and after some problems, managed to build the library without errors.

The thing is: when I try to use Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk()) in the app which uses that lib, it gives me an "symbol cannot be resolved".

I've tried moving this line into the lib, but all I've got was a NoClassDefFoundError.

Any suggestions?

Below, my lib gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 9
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/mylib.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

and my app gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.test.app'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name: 'my-framework', ext: 'aar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
}
```

Comment: after some ponderations, I think I know now the name of the problem: transitive dependencies. no solution yet though..

Comment: If you are using the library as local aar, it doesn't have the dependencies.
The solution is to add the crashlitycs dependencies also in the app.

Comment: I've tried that, the result is the same as when I had crashlytics only on the app..